# Angular 6 + Spring Boot. Wrong appearance of the application without index.html in the address bar

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, angular-cli

Please tell me why I could have the following problem:
After the application is assembled, this window appears in the browser.
[image]
The application will load correctly if you add `index.html` in the address bar
But then when you try to refresh the page goes Whitelabel Error Page.
I don’t know what is better to show, except for the content of the `angular.json` and `tconfig.json` (if you need to show something else - please tell me).
Thank you all in advance.

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "asterisk-prime-ui": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../../../../asterisk-prime/src/main/resources/static/asterisk-prime-ui",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/styles/global.scss"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "asterisk-prime-ui:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "asterisk-prime-ui:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "asterisk-prime-ui:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/styles/global.scss"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "asterisk-prime-ui-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "asterisk-prime-ui:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "asterisk-prime-ui:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "asterisk-prime-ui",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "/",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "es7",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "../../node_modules"
  ]
}
```

In addition, if you add to the address bar `.../index.html`, then there are errors when working

```
core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk modules-devices-devices-module-ngfactory failed.
(error: http://localhost:8080/asterisk_prime/modules-devices-devices-module-ngfactory.js)
Error: Loading chunk modules-devices-devices-module-ngfactory failed.
(error: http://localhost:8080/asterisk_prime/modules-devices-devices-module-ngfactory.js)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete (bootstrap:134)
    at HTMLScriptElement.wrapFn (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1332)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:3815)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:195)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:498)
    at invokeTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1744)
    at HTMLScriptElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1770)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:788)
    at zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:3815)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1744)
```

### UPDATED

Added clarification: Angular-application is used in assembled form as static resources for backend on Spring Boot. The application itself is collected in a war-file and deployed to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision required changes in both the backend (Spring Boot) and the frontend (Angular 6).

### 1. Backend

In the Spring Boot part, all changes were made to adjust WebMvc settings. In particular, changed the `ViewResolver`:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver()
{
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(InternalResourceView.class);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

And also added a "flip" to `index.html` when mapping `/` (as it turned out, this, in its own way, is the standard mechanism when using a single-page application (using Angular, React, or similar):

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry)
{
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index.html");
}
```

Final configuration view:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.prime.asterisk.web.controller"})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Value("#{'${web.mvc.crossOrigins}'.split(',')}")
    private String[] crossOrigins;

    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/",
            "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/",
            "classpath:/public/",
            "classpath:/static/asterisk-prime-ui/"
    };

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**"))
        {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                    .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedOrigins(crossOrigins)
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index.html");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(InternalResourceView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

### 2. Frontend

In part of the UI, it was also necessary to make your edits.

First of all, add the `base-href` and `deploy-url` attributes for the build scripts. In my case, the template used is: `/<application-context>/`, where `<application-context>` is `asterisk-prime` (for me). In general, in most cases it would be enough to put the `base-href` attribute, but in my case it was not enough, because project assets did not use base-href as a prefix to the src attribute. Perhaps there is another solution, but in my case it was enough to add the attribute `deploy-url`. The final view of the scripts:

```
...
"build-prod": "ng build --prod --base-href /asterisk-prime/ --deploy-url /asterisk-prime/",
...
"build-dev": "ng build --aot --build-optimizer --base-href /asterisk-prime/ --deploy-url /asterisk-prime/",
...
```

P.S .: `AppConfigRoutesFactory` - a class with a static method of return Routes (just pass your Routes there)

The final view of the `AppRoutesModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppConfigRoutesFactory.getRoutes(),
      {
        useHash: true,
        scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
      })
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Then you just need to import this module into your AppModule. You should use hash in the routing if the Whitelabel Error Page error comes out when refreshing the page.

Thank you all very much for all the assistance provided, for the comments and attempts at least to help in the direction of finding a problem.